# Как сохранить toggle class, цвет элемента li

Tags: javascript

Есть список `ul li`, который хранит в себе данные вписанные пользователем в формы. Данные добавляются в `li` и в `localStorage` объект(данные не пропадают при обновлении) если кликнуть на элемент списка, то цвет станет зеленым, класс `checked`. Это небольшой `todolist`. Так вот как сохранить этот `toggle` класс? Чтобы пользователь мог осуществить `refresh` страницы, а цвет выделенных пунктов оставался выделенным и не обновлялся. Решение данной проблемы есть в интернете, но либо на `Jquery`, либо непонятными мне способами. Как сохранить состояние(класс)? Какую технологию использовать? Тот же `JSON` либо `Cookie`. Помогите мне пожалуйста, очень долго ломаю голову над данной проблемой.

```
html
____
<ul>
   <li>one item</li>
   <li>two item</li>
   <li>three item</li>
</ul>

js
____
var li = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

for(var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    li[i].onclick = function(ev) {
       ev.target.classList.toggle('checked');
    }
}

css
____
.checked {color: green;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Xм, Вы же сохраняете объекты в `localStorage` (где, кстати, этот код?). Сохраняйте объекты со свойством `checked` и восстанавливайте `class`, ориентируясь на это свойство.

Храните в массиве не строки, а объекты в таком виде:

```
var data = {
  todo: [
    {
      text: "Buy groceries",
      done: true
    },
    {
      text: "Wash dishes",
      done: true
    },
    {
      text: "Do homework",
      done: false
    }
  ],
  ...
};

...
if (item.done)
  element.classList.add("checked");
```

Comment: код я не писал сюда, потому что 100 строк кода, думаю не влезло бы

Comment: То что вы написали у меня уже есть(ну схоже),  я просто не понимаю как быть дальше if(item.checked) - то сохранить его в localStorage. То есть сохранить класс в localStorage чтобы refresh не сбивал цвета. А это сделать уже не каждый сможет